# Dataset subseting based on selectInput() gives always a dataset with the same number of rows

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below and I use a `selectInput()` to subset the `iris` dataset based on `Species`. While this seems to work a strange thing happens. Whatever choice I make-even all of them- I always get 50 entries in the table which of course is wrong.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("select", label = "Select", 
                choices = unique(iris[,5]), 
                selected = "virginica",multiple = T)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("d")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$d<-renderDataTable({
    ir<-subset(iris, Species==input$select)

    datatable(ir)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There are 50 observations per species in the iris data. Nothing is wrong.

Comment: so if I select all I should get 150 entries not 50

Comment: Since you use `multiple = TRUE`, try `subset(iris, Species %in% input$select)`, since `input$select` can be a vector

Comment: that was it thanks